# Flutter changing system navigation bar icon brightness

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created 2 themes for my app a dark and a light one.
These themes work perfectly on any phone except samsung s10 phones.
On samsung s10 phones when the app is first started and the call to `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle` is made the navigation bar's icon color are not filled, it looks like only the borders are the color which I defined:

[image]

As soon as I tab out of the app and back in the icons look as they should.

[image]

This is also how it looks on any other phone when the app is started - as expected (but not for samsung s10).

This is the theme:

```
final DarkTheme = ThemeWrapper(
  themeData: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    accentColor: const Color(0xFF1976D2)
  ), 
  systemOverlay: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Color(0xFF222222),
      systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarColor: Color(0xFF222222),
  ),
);
```

And this is how I apply the systemUi:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(DarkTheme.systemOverlay);
```

Any Help woud be really appreciated.

Edit: This is indeed a flutter issue and not an android issue:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(Color.parseColor("#222222"));
    }
}
```

This simple android native code achieves exactly what I need even on samsung s10 phones.

Comment: Same in Samsung s8. Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @Charger512, Sorry for the delayed response. I have found a workaround but not necessarily a solution. Basically everytime the "View" is resumed I re-apply the SystemUiOverlayStyle and then it works.